# Symfony2 Sylius assets install

Tags: symfony, installation, assets, sylius

I am trying to install assets on my sylius project, and I am facing problem :

COMMAND: *php app/console sylius:install:assets*

ERROR AFTER EXECUTING COMMAND: *This command terminated with a permission error*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution of a problem, before you guys try to install assets be sure to clear cache, but you might get into a trouble with memory, so edit your

app/console file and add ini_set('memory_limit','-1');

and after that run cache clear, and install assets and everything will be fine :)